# getting ANR when switching between Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

in my application I use 2 Fragments for my `LoginActivity`: `LoginFragMain` and `LoginFragWebView`. After entering the `LoginActivity` the user sees the `LoginFragMain`, after a `View` click the `LoginFragWebView` is shown.

The second `Fragment` contains a `WebView`, which does not currently load any url, but only gets initialized. In the `Activity` I switch between `Fragments` like:

```
    private void swapFrags(String fragmentToShowTag) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (fragmentToShowTag.equals(TAG_FRAG_LOGIN_MAIN)) {
        ft.hide(mLoginFragWeb);
        ft.show(mLoginFragMain);
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        ft.hide(mLoginFragMain);
        ft.show(mLoginFragWeb);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

To allow the user to cancel authorization I have overridden the `onBackPressed()`:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mLoginFragWeb.isVisible())
        swapFrags(TAG_FRAG_LOGIN_MAIN);
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**The problem:** when back is pressed, the Fragments get swapped correctly. However, when I press back again to close the app, it freezes for a while and then I'm getting an `ANR`. Dalvikvm only reports it wrote stack traces to `data/anr/traces.txt`. I checked those and found a very long log which I do not understand. For size reasons, I used [pastebin for those logs](http://pastebin.com/9hPFUR1v). My test devices is Nexus 5 @ 4.4.4

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a browser issue:

> "CleanupReference" daemon prio=5 tid=14 WAIT   | group="main"
>   sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4264c778 self=0x75ecb1b8   | sysTid=16122
>   nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1978447376   | state=S schedstat=(
>   94792 21093 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native
>   Method)
>     - waiting on <0x4264c6b0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
>
> at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
>
> at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
>
> at
>   com.android.org.chromium.content.common.CleanupReference$1.run(CleanupReference.java:49)

Just use any other fragment without webview and see if you still see the error.This will help to isolate the cause for the issue.

Comment: yep, I tried to use a different `Layout` which only contains a `TextView` for this `Fragment`, but the issue persists

Comment: @Droidman  does the textview has linkify option...just keep a fragment with empty layout..if you linkify anything it will bring the entire browser stack up..

Comment: this `TextView` is just a `TextView` since for test purposes I used the default layout generated by ADT for an empty `Activity`

Comment: remove textview from the view...just empty layout

Comment: actually I tried launching an empty `Activity` and I also got an ANR on exit.. very strange behavior

Comment: nvm m8, that was my dumbness

Answer (score 0):

oh well, I figured it out and want to say sorry for polluting SO with such questions. I had a splash screen which is not visible and I totally forgot to `finish()` it, so it caused an infinite loop. This happens when you don't pay attention.